# Equivalent of SKStoreProductViewController for Android?

Tags: java, android, ios, kotlin

I want to cross promote another of my apps from inside my app, with an interstitial inside my app, as it can be done on iOS with SKStoreProductViewController.

Is it possible to do that on Android ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link to your playstore app and have an icon with your other app's icon. Post that fire a intent to go to the market and open your app install page

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageNameOfYourOtherApp)));
```

Comment: Apple solution is much better : 1) the user does not quit the app 2) can install the app directly from the panel coming over the app. Same difference as allowing rating in the app or redirecting the user to the store to rate ; not at all the same user experience.